# C# integration test run per connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, integration-testing, devart

We have an application that uses Entity Code First and we have added Devart for Oracle support.  We have a series of integration tests that run through Visual Studio test runner that cover seed data testing.  We would like to be able to run these tests for a SQL Server as well as Oracle at the time of test execution.  Does anyone have a good angle to approach this?

Comment: Run the test twice.  Once for each type.

Comment: Hoping for something a little more lazy and automatable.  The set of tests will be ever expanding and we don't want to add exponential maintenance.  If you know of a simple procedure for making this automated that may cover our needs. Also note: these tests are run on Gated check-in.

Comment: I think what you are failing to understand is these should be treated as TWO separate tests.  You are testing two separate platforms - even though they are going through the same operations.  Automate this at the build level - and just run the suite twice - each run with a separate database target.

Comment: I understand that these are two test runs.  My question is more focused on how to automate these two runs. This automation must be run for two connection strings and I do not know how to set this up within TFS.  I am looking for either setup steps or a direction I should follow for figuring out how to find the steps I need.  We do not have anyone on staff that is that experienced with the Visual Studio Test runner or TFS automation.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JamieYoung - You should make that comment a part of the question or a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the connection string and other setup info from a configuration file.

Make a configuration file per database/setup.

Make a command file that executes the tests twice once with each configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want different environment settings yet still only code the test once but run many times, how about a [Data Driven test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

You could decorate your test with the `[DataSource]` attribute. The datasource itself could be an excel file, a CSV, etc., and the file could hold the connection strings, plus other relevant information in order to configure the environment.

Within each run of the test you will have a DataRow that represents your environment data.

The same could be accomplished if you are using NUnit as well, using the [`[ValueSource]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5) attribute, and provide the data from some storage location, a file, a static method on the class returning values, etc.

With any of these setups, the test will actually run MULTIPLE times, so that each environment can fail or pass individually.

This is also a very good approach to test one piece of logic but with different scenarios and expected outputs. You could have the inputs and expected outputs within an external datasource and have the testing framework run through all scenarios and ensure they all still work as expected. This may be useful to do black-box testing for things like financial algorithms that you want to check against maybe already known results, or the same algorithm in excel, for example, in cases where you have hundreds of scenarios to compare.

This is obviously not to say that you shouldn't write actual unit tests for isolated classes, it's just another tool to add to the toolbox.

Comment: Note that you can only add the DataSource attribute only once: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Correct, the idea is to have a single data-source, with multiple rows, one for each environment.